# Ayuds vb imagen inhabilitada, código no funciona

Tags: vba, vb

tal vez ya estoy demasiado abrumada y no veo algo evidente. Tengo una subrutina, durante dos segundos y medio la pantalla debe oscurecerse completamente, deben de ser invisibles los botones y labels que hay y luego del tiempo deben volver a ser visibles, además debe estar habilitado uno de los botones. Tengo este código, pero luego de que la pantalla se oscurece y los objetos vuelven a aparecer el boton no se habilita. Tienen alguna idea de por qué?

```
 Sub BO_E() 


        Iniciar_Ref()

        EBtCOn.Visible = False
        BtCOff.Visible = False

        ERI.Visible = False
        EVI.Visible = False
        BtnIzqOff.Visible = False

        EVD.Visible = False
        ERD.Visible = False
        BtnDerOff.Visible = False

        Me.BackColor = Color.Black

        Do
            If Duración_Ref() > 2500 Then Exit Do '<Duracion de 2.5 s
            My.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightGray

        EBtCOn.Visible = False
        BtCOff.Visible = False

        ERI.Visible = False
        EVI.Visible = False
        BtnIzqOff.Visible = False

        EVD.Visible = False
        ERD.Visible = False
        BtnDerOff.Visible = False

        revivir_tiempo()'<------ esto puede ignorarse
        y = 0
    End Sub
```

Comment: Visible no deberia de ser true, para que se vea adespues del loop??? tienes todo en false

Answer (score 0):

tiene pinta de ser error de flujo.

si Oscureces todo a la vez, sepáralo en una función distinta y según el estado de uno de ellos ocultas o visibilizas.

algo así...

Flujo principal:

```vb
Sub BO_E() 

    Iniciar_Ref()
    
    Oculto_Visible_Objetos() ' función para analizar el estado de los objetos
    
    Me.BackColor = Color.Black

    Do
        If Duración_Ref() > 2500 Then Exit Do '<Duracion de 2.5 s
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    Me.BackColor = Color.LightGray

    Oculto_Visible_Objetos()

    revivir_tiempo()'<------ esto puede ignorarse
    y = 0
End Sub
```

Según el estado de uno de los objetos, tratas el resto.

```vb
function Oculto_Visible_Objetos()
    if EBtCOn.Visible = False then
        EBtCOn.Visible = true
        BtCOff.Visible = true

        ERI.Visible = true
        EVI.Visible = true
        BtnIzqOff.Visible = true

        EVD.Visible = true
        ERD.Visible = true
        BtnDerOff.Visible = true
    else
        EBtCOn.Visible = False
        BtCOff.Visible = False

        ERI.Visible = False
        EVI.Visible = False
        BtnIzqOff.Visible = False

        EVD.Visible = False
        ERD.Visible = False
        BtnDerOff.Visible = False
    end if
end function
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado bastante.

Comment: Me alegro!
Si te ha servido la respuesta por favor, vótala :)